# Ionic capacitor android emulator make Console log visible in terminal

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I would like to be able to see `console.log` messages in terminal when using Android emulator with capacitor.

HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="callSomething($event)">
  Console something
</button>
```

TS

```
  public callSomething() {
    console.log('Hello  World!!!');
  }
```

terminal command

> **ionic capacitor run android --livereload --external --consolelogs**

[image]

when I click button  "console something", nothing is printed in terminal

Comment: inspect it via Chrome Debugger.

Comment: Why don't you use chrome://inspect or Android Studio logging tool?

Comment: I do use chrome://inspect, but sometimes I think having it shown in terminal is faster than opening a new browser just to see a console message.